# Elegant serialization/deserialization of enum with associated values

Tags: swift, enums

I would like to use enum with associated values for type-safe `NSNotification`s:

```
enum Notification {
   case Foo(Int)
   case Bar

   var rawValue: String { 
      switch self {
          case .Foo:
              return "Foo"

          case .Bar:
              return "Bar"
      }
   }

   var asNSNotification: NSNotification {
      let userInfo = [String: AnyObject]()

      switch self {
          case let .Foo(intVal):
              userInfo["intVal": intVal]

          default:
              break
      }

      return NSNotification(name: rawValue, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
   }

   init?(fromNSNotification n: NSNotification) {
      switch n.name {
          case .Bar: 
              self = .Bar

          case .Foo(42): // some bogus value
              let realValue = n.userInfo?["intVal"] ?? 0
              self = .Foo(realValue)

          default:
              return nil
      }
   }
}
```

This should work, but it sure is an ugly piece of code. Anyone has ideas how to make it more elegant?

---

**EDIT**: the reason why I want to use enum is to make parameters of each notification type-safe.

By "more elegant" I mean:

1. Simplify `rawValue` property (avoid having to `switch`)
2. Avoid "bogus values" when referencing enum cases with associated values in
   initializer.
3. Anything that would reduce verbosity and improve
   readability.

---

Okay, here's how `rawValue` property can be simplified:

```
var rawValue: String {
    return Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first.flatMap({ $0.label }) ?? "\(self)"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have figured out how to make the handling of `NSNotification`s more elegant:

```
enum NotificationType: String {
   case Foo
   case Bar
}

enum Notification {
   case Foo(Int)
   case Bar

   // the fragile part
   var type: NotificationType { 
      let name = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first.flatMap({ $0.label }) ?? "\(self)"
      return NotificationType(rawValue: name)!
   }

   var asNSNotification: NSNotification {
      let name = type.rawValue
      let userInfo = [String: AnyObject]()

      switch self {
          case let .Foo(intVal):
              userInfo["intVal": intVal]

          default:
              break
      }

      return NSNotification(name: name, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
   }

   init?(fromNSNotification n: NSNotification) {
      let type = NotificationType(rawValue: n.name)!

      switch type {
          case .Bar: 
              self = .Bar

          case .Foo:
              let value = n.userInfo?["intVal"] ?? 0
              self = .Foo(value)

          default:
              return nil
      }
   }
}
```

This solution relies on the convention that case names in `Notification` and `NotificationType` are the same. One might say that such design is fragile, but I think this is little tradeoff compared to what we achieve.

Below is a little helper class to handle subscription/unsubscription:

```
protocol NotificationReceiving: class {
    func didReceiveNotification(notification: Notification)
}

class NotificationReceiver {

    private weak var delegate: NotificationReceiving?

    private(set) var subscriptions = Set<NotificationType>()

    init(delegate: NotificationReceiving?) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func subscribe(notificationTypes: NotificationType...) {
        let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        let doSubscribe: NotificationType -> Void = {
            nc.addObserver(self, selector: "handleNotification:", name: $0.name, object: nil)
            self.subscriptions.insert($0)
        }

        notificationTypes.forEach(doSubscribe)
    }

    func unsubscribe(notificationTypes: NotificationType...) {
        let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

        if notificationTypes.isEmpty {
            nc.removeObserver(self)
        } else {
            let doUnsubscribe: NotificationType -> Void = {
                nc.removeObserver(self, name: $0.name, object: nil)
                self.subscriptions.remove($0)
            }

            notificationTypes.forEach(doUnsubscribe)
        }
    }

    @objc private func handleNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let n = Notification(fromNSNotification: notification) {
            delegate?.didReceiveNotification(n)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how a client might look:

```
class Client: NotificationReceiving {
    private var receiver: NotificationReceiver!

    init() {
        receiver = NotificationReceiver(delegate: self)
        receiver.subscribe(.Foo, .Bar)
    }

    deinit {
        receiver.unsubscribe()
    }

    func didReceiveNotification(notification: Notification) {
        switch notification {
        case let .Foo(val):
            print("foo with val: \(val)")
            // this notification is one-shot:
            receiver.unsubscribe(.Foo)

        case .Bar:
            print("bar!")
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure handling all notifications in one method is good design (I guess it might get messy when there are many notifications), but the point is that we can now use the power of type safety and pattern matching, which is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that your enum is working too hard. This should be sufficient:

```
enum Notification {
    case Foo(Int)
    case Bar
    func notification() -> NSNotification {
        switch self {
        case Foo(let intVal):
            return NSNotification(name: "Foo", object: nil, userInfo: ["IntVal":intVal])
        case Bar:
            return NSNotification(name: "Bar", object: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the ability to supply a non-nil `object` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: yeah, this definitely solves the problem of serialization, thanks :) But desezialization (see the initializer) is still quite awkward. I see that your solution does not include the deserialization at all. How do you think the reception of this notification would look?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve there, sorry. Your idea of turning a notification "back" into an enum seems to me to go way overboard. If it's crucial, hey, include a copy of the enum itself in the notification user info! But it seems nutty to me.

Comment: *turning a notification "back" into an enum*

yeah, that's the idea.

*include a copy of the enum itself in the notification user info*

can't do that, it's not an `AnyObject`